# multivariate analysis for seasonal patterns among rivers

Tags: sampling, multivariate-analysis, ecology, exploratory-data-analysis

I sampled three different rivers over one year during the four seasons. In addition, in the autumn and winter seasons I sampled both during an event of high (drought period) and low water (flood period). I have 3 categorical variables (river, season, event) and 11 continuous (environmental parameters, like oxygen, temperature, pH, no3, etc...).
The goal is to assess the degree of similarity-diversity of the three rivers, the influence of the seasons and flood-drought periods on the environmental parameters.
I was thinking about a set of multivariate techniques among:
1)redundancy analysis
2)canonical correspondence analysis
3)multiple factor analysis
4)factor analysis of mixed data.
Which, in your opinion, would better answer the questions stated above?
Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: In your case, I'd go for a Multiple Co-Inertia analysis. See Fig. 3D in this paper https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1890/03-0178 . From your description, it seems this is exactly what you have

Comment: Both CCA and RDA require at least two tables/matrices. And it seems you only have one matrix with 11 variables, and then 2 factors, each with 2 levels. River is not a factor, but your sampling unit

Comment: Thank you Diogo for the link, I'll study it! Just in this case, I presume, "rivers" is still a factor cause identify three different watersheds, while the sampling stations in each river can be counted as the sampling units. I recently discovered the nMDS maybe it can fit my case?